# How to put Magic Trackpad 2 into Discovery Mode

Tags: bluetooth, trackpad, magic-trackpad

I have a Magic Trackpad 2.  I previously had it paired with my Mac.  I then had it set up to work with another computer.  I now want to use it with my Mac again and it will not work.

I have followed the suggestions in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21318/how-to-set-already-paired-bluetooth-devices-again-into-discovery-mode) to no avail.

I have tried resetting the Bluetooth module on my mac.  I have tried clearing all the connected devices from my mac.  The trackpad is fully charged.  It works when connected via a wire.  I've tried turning the trackpad on and off and that does not help.  My Mac just can not see it via Bluetooth.

Is there a way to force the Magic Trackpad 2 into discovery mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To setup a Magic Trackpad 2 you have to connect it to your Mac using the Lightning cable.

Connect the Trackpad, make sure device's power is on, setup using Bluetooth section of System Preferences.

Here is the Apple support article with the steps I described:

[Set up your Apple wireless mouse, keyboard, and trackpad](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201178)

Comment: So I do think this is the correct answer but it was not working for me originally.  I did a reboot (I should have done this earlier in the try to get things working process) and then this worked.